# Print out a method from one java class when called from a 2nd java class

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA and am attempting to call a method from a class that prints out a message using the same method within another class. I am very new to java and really want to learn.

What I want to do is call the getAllCustomerInfo() method from the CustomerInfo{} class which is being called from the Customer class. When I try to run the code I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c

If I make c static (static Customer c = new Customer();) and try to run my code it only prints the commas out from the getAllCustomerInfo() method and not the getName(), getAddress etc information.

Any ideas? Thank you.

CLASS 1:

```
public class Customer {
    //Assume I have getters and setters and fields

    //Method I want to use in another class
    public String getAllCustomerInfo() {
        String message =
            getName() + "\n" +
            getAddress() + "\n" +
            getAge();

        System.out.println(message);

        return message;
    }

} //END OF CUSTOMER CLASS
```

CLASS2:

```
//Class I am trying to call method from
public class CustomerInfo {
    Customer c = new Customer();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Code where I am trying to access the method from the Customer class


        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

            System.out.print("Enter a customer number: ");
            int customerNumber = sc.nextInt();

            String customerInformation = sc.nextLine();

            // get the Product object
            Customer customer = CustomerDB.getCustomer(customerNumber);

            //Check if customer exits in DB
            if (customerNumber == 1) {
                // display the output
                System.out.println(c.getAllCustomerInfo());
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no one like that in the DB.");
            }

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: What is your question exactly?  Please provide a complete example that actually runs, if you're able to do that. "the same method within another class" ?  I don't know what that means.

Comment: The first problem I see here is that you are defining a member variable 'c' in your CustomerInfo class, but you aren't creating an instance of that class.  The reference to 'c' in your main wont work because you're in a static method, and therefore you aren't in an instance of a CustomerInfo object, which is what would have 'c' defined in it.  I get that you're new to Java.  I'd suggest starting VERY simple.  Start with something that will run, and then add little by little, and ask questions if you have to about just the last line you added that broke your code.

Comment: Updated the code @Steve

Comment: @kai - I get this error on the line (c.getAllCustomerInfo()) ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c

Comment: You still have the same problem.  Your reference to 'c' in your main() isn't valid.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's what I'm saying.  You can make that variable static and it will work..."static Customer c = new Costomer()".

Comment: Steve: now I changed my instantiation to static and the error dissapears (static Customer c = new Customer();) BUT now when I run the code the output shows up as only printing the commas from the original method

Comment: So from this code:  getName() + "\n" +getAddress() + "\n" + getAge();                      Only the commas print and not the actual customer info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188777/discussion-between-steve-and-wca).

Answer (score 1):

In the `CustomerInfo` class, `c` is a instance variable which will not exist without an object instance of `CustomerInfo` class. Since you are referring it from static context you will get such error. You have to make `c` variable `static` or move it inside the `main` method.

```
public class CustomerInfo{
   static Customer c = new Customer();
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // your implementation
   }
}
```

OR

```
public class CustomerInfo{
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Customer c = new Customer();
      // your implementation
   }
}
```